# New link added in user page but not visible to non admin user in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, routes, users

I added this module in Drupal 7 for adding new tab in my site. This new tab is not visible to non admin  user. Only visible to admin. I also tried to set permission in this direction admin> People> permission but this there is no module by the name "New tab" is visible. Please help.

```
function newtab_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['user/%user/new_tab'] = array(
    'title' => 'New tab title', 
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', 
    'page arguments' => array('newtab_newtab_form', 1), 
    'access arguments' => array('access new tab'), 
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK, 
  );

  return $items;
}

function newtab_newtab_form($form, &$form_state, $account) {
  // ...
}

function newtab_permission() {
  return array(
    'access new tab' => array(
      'title' => t('The title of the permission'),
      'description' => t('The description of the permission'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815765/drupal-tab-is-not-visible-to-non-admin-users? (ok, not exactly... ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your problem is that you haven't defined your permission. You can demand any permission, even ones that doesn't exist.

To create permissions, you use [`hook_permission`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7):

```
function newtab_permission() {
  return array(
    'access new tab' => array(
      'title' => t('Access new tab'),
      'description' => t('The description of the permission'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I have added the hook_permission in newtan.module page but still this is not showing in permission page. My version is Drupal 7

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your permission with [hook_permission()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7).

```
function newtab_permission() {
  return array(
    'access new tab' = > array(
      'title' => t('Access new tab'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: @Berdir  I have added the hook_permission in newtab.module page but still this is not showing in permission page. My version is Drupal 7

Comment: Show your code... (you can edit the question)

Comment: function newtab_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['user/%user/new_tab'] = array(
    'title' => 'New tab title', 
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', 
    'page arguments' => array('newtab_newtab_form', 1), 
    'access arguments' => array('access new tab'), 
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK, 
  );
  return $items;
}
function newtab_newtab_form($form, &$form_state, $account) {
}
function newtab_permission() {
  return array(
    'access new tab' => array(
      'title' => t('The title of the permission'),
      'description' => t('The description of the permission'),
    ),
  );
}

Comment: Well, you named your permission 'The title of the permission'. Also, make sure to clear the cache after adding new hooks. And again, edit your question instead of adding it as a comment. This is not readable.

Comment: @Berdir I have cleared the cache. Edited the question also.